Is there a way to find undecorated classes/functions in a Python module?
I'm trying to write a tool which will help me find implementation bugs in a large existing python code base that makes heavy use of decorators.
Lets say I have a file, rules.py:
manager = RuleManager()

@manager.register
class A:
    pass

class B:
    pass


Lets say I already know ahead of time what the Manager classes are that use the decorator.
How would I find that class B is undecorated?
Ideally the output would include something like /path/to/rules.py:`B` is undecorated by any manager

Depends what the decorator does to the class. You can iterate over any members of a module like you'd iterate any other object, so listing all classes in a module shouldn't be too hard. Then you just need some detection criterion like the class not being registered in your list, or not being of a certain type, or not having some attribute that the decorator is expected to set.

I'd look on https://github.com/ast-grep/ast-grep as it seems the tool that can handle it. Perhaps, adding a similar tag might be enough to pay attention to the question.

Use ast.parse to parse the syntax tree in each file, then fetch all ClassDef's with an empty decorator list and report their relative location:
from ast import parse, walk, ClassDef, Attribute

# define predicate to test decorator list for presence of @manager.register
def has_decorator(deco_list):
  for deco in deco_list:
    if isinstance(deco, Attribute) and d.value.id == 'manager' and d.attr == 'register':
      return True
  return False

# parse input text
with open("/path/to/file.py") as f:
  source_tree = parse(f.read())

# traverse the tree, inspect all class defs for the decorator
for node in walk(source_tree):
  if isinstance(node, ClassDef) and not has_decorator(node.decorator_list):
    print(f"Class '{node.name}' on line {node.lineno} has no expected decorators")


Thank you! Is there a way to check the decorator against a list of known good decorators?

@ijustlovemath You're most welcome! I've updated the answer with an example of how you could filter for a specific decorator - you can obviously expand that, but for more than 3 distinct decorators I'd probably rewrite it at two separate functions (1 to filter the list, separate one to compare each decorator to a known-good one) :)

You can use a regexp with a negative lookbehind:
(?<!@manager\.register\n)class .*

DEMO
